# Send a file via SFTP to a Docker Container

Tags: networking, docker, sftp, file-transfer

I have a Docker container running with an app on Linux. The container is hosted on a Mac(development) or AWS(production). I want to be able to send a file to this container remotely. How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install a SSH server in the image you are running, or make sure one is already installed. Then you need to map the ssh port (default 22) on your container to the host's port so you can reach your container from outside host. For example:

```
docker run -p 10022:22 app_container
```

If running on AWS check your security group for that ec2 instance you are running that container on to allow host port (10022 as in example above) to be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 5):

You may also use "docker cp" to copy from/to container and local drive.

Be aware of the syntax. * is not possible, but cp is recursive and copies directories...
So e.g.

```bash
docker cp c867cee9451f:/var/www/html/themes/ .
```

copies the whole themes folder with subdirectories to your local drive while

```bash
docker cp c867cee9451f:/var/www/html/themes/* .  #### does not work
```

won't work.